# 12VDC 18Amps dangerous?

Tags: voltage, dc, amperage

I have an old PSU which has an output of 18Amps at 12Volts DC. Is it dangerous if I touch the wires? Or is the voltage too low to jump my body (I heard anything below 40 Volts DC can't be felt by your skin).

I won't open the casing of the PSU so I won't come in contact with the charged capacitors.

I'll use the PSU to power a HHO generator

[image]

Comment: It's not dangerous to you but it could set things on fire if it make contact with something else conductive.

Comment: The classic example is getting a wedding ring across a high current source and ending up with a really bad burn under the ring and maybe on your other fingers as you try to get it off.

Comment: Safe to touch with your skin, yes. But that is not the only hazard. It is enough power to heat up small wires, etc.

Answer (score 0):

All voltages below 50V are considered safe to touch.

although I would not advise putting -48V on your tongue to check if a phone line is working as the ring voltage is much higher. ( although I have )

You can try a 9V battery on your fingers then your knee , and you might be able to feel it. Your tongue will feel a strong burning sensation with a quick 9V battery test.

However you can create high voltage spikes with any inductive coil break in current from a low voltage.

Also beware that >4% Hydrogen concentration (LEL) is considered explosive to static discharges in that container.

Comment: He's making "Brown's gas" (a stoichiometric mixture of hydrogen and oxygen). Kaboom indeed.

Comment: So even though the current is 18Amps it's save to 'accidently' touch?

Comment: @OlivierGroeneveld, Safe for you to touch if you take off rings, watches. But a 12v supply can create sparks that set off Spehro's **kaboom** when you make/break connections to it.